# How can I remove negators: potential shouldn't be so ‘fanciful or remote’ that the proferens can't be supposed to desire protection from it?

Tags: legalese

> [1.] [T]he potential for non-negligence liability should **not** be so ‘fanciful or remote’ that the [proferens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proferens) can**not** be supposed to desire protection from it.

How can I rewrite 1 without any **not**, while changing as few lexical words as possible? 2 beneath is my attempt, and I colored in grey my changes. But 2 feels inaccurate as 2 makes 'fanciful or remote' appear attainable and craved, but 1 highlights that  'fanciful or remote' are undesired.

> [2.] [T]he potential for non-negligence liability should  <s>**not**</s> be ‘fanciful or remote’ `only if` the [proferens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proferens) can<s>**not**</s>  be supposed to desire protection from it.

## Afterword (merely for context, but unnecessary)

ODO defines [proferens](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proferens). Left picture's from p. 400 in  Mindy Chen-Wishart's [*Contract Law* (2018 6 edn)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Mindy-Chen-Wishart/dp/0198806353/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).
Right is Steyn LJ's judgment in *E.E. Caledonia Ltd. v Orbit Valve Co. Europe* [[1994] 1 W.L.R. 1515](http://login.westlaw.co.uk/maf/wluk/ext/app/document?crumb-action=reset&docguid=IA01CCB30E42711DA8FC2A0F0355337E9).

[image]

Comment: Please don't use illegible images to convey important information. Actually type out the phrases you've highlighted. Also, context is almost always necessary, which is why you've included it here.

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it in the first place? It makes sense as it is.

Comment: “Only when the potential for non-negligence liability is so fanciful or remote can the proferens be supposed to desire no protection from it.”    or “... can the proferens be supposed to forgo protection from it.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If “fanciful or remote” are undesired characteristics, first state the preferred situation which assumes that they are not present, and then add them back. You can do that using ***unless.***

> The proferens may be supposed to desire protection from the potential for non-negligence liability unless that potential is fanciful or remote.

Although the repeated *that potential* here could simply be *it,* that might be ambiguous and restating the noun itself is certainly clearer.

**However, rewording the sentence changes the emphasis.** In this version, we look at things from the proferens’ point of view; in the original, it considers the potential for liability.